# In-App Billing in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am implementing In-App Billing in my app since 3 days. The sample code provided is working fine but when i am merging that code with my original app with the modifications like:

```
1.Changing Public Key in Security.java
2.changed the package names in all classes.
3.Changed product name in code and product list in Android market.
4.Signed ,Uploaded and Activated the .apk in Android market.
```

is there any more modifications i should do in code. But i am not getting the response from the android or google play as JSON for purchase state for the particular item which i have purchased.

And it is also asking for "Accept and Buy " using Credit or Debit Card.

But not getting any response please help me to get rid of this .

Every time when i make transaction for the purchasing of a product it is responding in LOG as DEVELOPER ERROR and RESULT ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this plugin](https://github.com/poiuytrez/phonegap-plugins/tree/billingPlugin/Android/InAppBilling) (I claim no credit for developing it!) and got it to work in 15 minutes.